# Provisioning tab missing xcode 7

Tags: xcode, provisioning

I'm trying to code signing and archive and development build for my app. But strangely I did not see the provisioning choosing tab (normally it under Code signing). Is there any way to bring back the provisioning menu under build settings? Any help is much appreciate. Thanks!

[image: xcode]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select "All" option from top.

Please check image.

[image]